# jQuery fadeIn not working on firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have my `body` tag set to `display:none`, and in document.ready, I do `$('body').fadeIn(1000);`.  It works on Chrome yet on FF the page stays `display:none`.

My site is [here](http://huddersfieldwebsitedesigner.co.uk/)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it don't link to site, should use jsfiddler instead

Comment: What file is `$('body').fadeIn(1000);` in?

Comment: you should really be doing this with a CSS keyframe animation, and saving the jQuery for Internet Exploder.

Comment: not sure how to do that

Comment: Voted to close question as ones the link to the site is dead it has little meaning to future users possibly looking here for a solution to a similar problem only to find a dead link and answer which have little context without any relevant code posted in the question.

Comment: Don't do this... if someone disables javascript, all they will see is a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was, as someone who has now deleted their comment said, the fact it was on the body.  I added a div inside the body and applied the styles and jquery on that and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fade in your body, use CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {    
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {    
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {    
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {    
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

Then on your body CSS:

```
body {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s linear 1; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s linear 1; /* Firefox */
    -o-animation: fadeIn 1s linear 1;  /* Opera */
    animation: fadeIn 1s linear 1;
}
```

That will handle everything except IE9-, will be much faster, and won't confuse the hell out of people who have Javascript disabled.

Comment: is the 1s one second?  whats linear 1?

Comment: `1s` = 1 second, and `linear` means a smooth gradient transition, rather than like `easeInOut` or something. the `1` after that just means perform the action once, rather than `infinite`. you also could express the time in milliseconds, i.e. `1000ms`, but i was keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have `display:none` on both the styles.css and inline.

Try removing it from the styles.css file since it's already declared inline.