# Smoothly Fade In Entire Web Page With MooTools

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools, mootools1.2

I want to fade in an entire web page after all its elements finished loading. The web page includes the background image repeated left to right, and the main content area with some text and pictures. I assume I should set body opacity to 0 in CSS, and use JavaScript code to fade in the page.

I have to use MooTools, more specifically, version 1.2.6, because that library is already linked to the page (and shouldn't be upgraded to a more recent version, for a number of reasons).

One of the StackOverflow experts suggested this MooTools snippet as a solution:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
  $$('body').set('morph', {duration: 300}).morph({'opacity': '1'});
});
```

**PROBLEM:** for some reason, instead of smoothly fading in the page, the snippet makes the background appear right away, and then, a second or so later, the page pops up, without any fade-in effect. Most likely it's me who's not doing things right.

I'd appreciate a bit of advice from a knowledgeable person.

Comment: man, i sure hope everyone that ever visits your site has javascript activated.

Comment: If they don't, they'll see a no-JS version of the site, no problem. Thank you for mentioning that, @LifeInGrey. Aside from your excellent observation, do you think you could contribute a solution to the problem I want help with? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: the problem is that this is bad practice, you shouldn't use JS to fadeIn your page. if anything, use CSS3 keyframe animations, which handles everything except IE9-. other than that, i cant solve a problem by creating a problem.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your strong and well-argumented opinion about this, @LifeInGrey. I like you suggestion about CSS3 keyframe animation – but could you please show me how you would do that?

Comment: certainly => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710472/jquery-fadein-not-working-on-firefox/15710582#15710582

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov i agree with LifeInTheGrey but i said i would answer your question if you had a follow-up so there you go.. also you can have a fallback for those who have js disabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is to do the following.

Remove the CSS `opacity:0;` in the stylesheet and use this code adjusted from yours

I increased from `300` to `3000` which in seconds is from `.3seconds` to `3seconds`.

chained:

```
window.addEvent('load', function () {

    $$('body').fade('hide').set('morph', {
        duration: 3000
    }).morph({
        'opacity': '1'
    });


});
```

expanded:

```
window.addEvent('load', function () {

    var el = $$('body');

    el.fade('hide'); // hide body tag

    el.set('morph', {duration: 3000});

    $$('body').morph({'opacity': '1'});


});
```

#### Notice:

I do agree with LifeInTheGrey about bad practice, but i said i would answer your question.

Comment: – this looks great, thank you, David – but what I don't understand is this: why does the background load immediately, and the content area fades in later?! With the initial snippet, the background loaded right away, and then a few moments later, the content just popped up. Now the content fades in smoothly, the way I wanted, but the background still loads first, for some reason!

Comment: P.S. Actually, there seems to be another issue. The page "blinks"! – that is, it load visible first, then fades out, and then fades in again. I just want it to fade in once, and stay visible. Help, please?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov take a look at my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/SSyer/ does your css have the opacity? you should remove it

Comment: – Can't see the fiddle, blocked by network admin in my office. Can you please take a look at this test page online? It blinks in Safari 6: http://cybart.org/testpage.html – and shows the background first, fading in content next, in FireFox 19. Thank you for dedicating so much of your time to this!

Comment: your html tags are missing and im getting a `404` not found error with `mootools-1.2.3.1-more.js` try also placing the code in the `<body>` tags at the bottom instead of the the `<head>`

Comment: Okay, @David Chase, this has improved! Thank you very much! But why place it in <body> and not in the <head>? Why does that makes a difference?

Comment: – oops, not really. Still blinking in Safari when placed online, can you please take a look? cybart.org/testpage.html

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov i usually load my libraries on top in `<head>` and my code in the bottom with an external file. i like to keep my code(html,css,js) separate. It also the page to load first and then execute the js..

Comment: does it blink if you switch `5000` instead of `500`

Comment: – It does, except it fades in VEEERY slowly afterwards. I think the problem is that the page loads first and is visible, than it hides, and then it fades in. What I need is the page to be invisible until it's loaded (including the bg) and then fade in. See what I mean?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov try adding the css `body {opacity:0;}` back in keep the js the same.

Comment: – yeah, but my comp has only English, k sozhaleniyu. A vy? I wanted also to ask you this: what is your reason for disapproving of this tactic, and agreeing with LifeInTheGrey in considering this bad practice? I just want to understand the implications, before I make any decisions about using the code you helped me with.

Comment: Санкт-Петербург, my only concern is for a site like http://tapquo.com/ which maybe using faux-ajax or ajax but if you turn off javascript it doesnt load, i dont really know that many people that have it turned off but if you have a fallback that already is in place then you shouldnt worry. if dont care about non modern browsers css3 is a nice way to go just in case there are any js errors such 404, etc.

Comment: NYC. Yeah, I see what you mean. Yep, I have the plan for no-JS cases, I will assign the class to <body> tag with JS, and set any CSS for JS-enabled site in that class. That way, those users who are dorky enough to switch off their JS will get no JS functionality, but the rest of the website will show. Thank you for explaining this and for helping with the main issue over such a long time!

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov no worries glad to help and right now im in Philly but im from st. petersburg :)